# Akeneo: Edit an attribute option

Tags: akeneo

I want to change an attribute option label and store it with Akeneo 1.4.9, but I don't know which handlers/factories I should use.

I used `MyAttributeOptionValueInterface->setLabel('new Label')` to change the label. How can I save the result in the database?

My idea:

1. Remove the old option from the attribute (`AttributeInterface->removeOption(optionWithOldLabel)`)
2. Add it again (`AttributeInterface->addOption(optionWithNewLabel)`)
3. Store the attribute in the database (how?).

Is this the correct way? Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use object savers of the PIM:  http://docs.akeneo.com/latest/cookbook/catalog/common/save.html?highlight=saver

And save your options like that:

```
$attributeOption->setLabel('My nice label');
$attributeOptionSaver = $this->getContainer()->get('pim_catalog.saver.attribute_option');
$attributeOptionSaver->save($attributeOption);
```

And you are good to go !

Comment: Thanks, updating an AttributeOption works with your answer :-). 

A related question: When I want to **add/remove** an option to an attribute, do I have to work with the AttributeInterface? How can I save these changes?

Comment: Ok, found it: For adding attribute options I can also use the `optionSaver` (`SaverInterface`), for removing attributes I can use the `optionRemover` (`RemoverInterface`)

Comment: Yep, you can use the propertyAdder and the propertyRemover (you can find details here: http://docs.akeneo.com/latest/cookbook/catalog/product/update.html?highlight=propertyadder)